Default jupyter kernel restarts after running script, but a new kernel does not
I've got the following container:
FROM base:latest

# Jupyter
RUN pip3 install jupyter -U && pip3 install jupyterlab

ENTRYPOINT ["jupyter", "lab","--ip=0.0.0.0","--NotebookApp.terminals_enabled=False", "--no-browser", "--allow-root", "--debug", "--log-level=DEBUG"]


Which works and gives me a full container running jupyter and the UI. I try to jupyter console --existing and run my test script but see it restarting:
root@3e04896b2103:/# jupyter console --existing
Jupyter console 6.6.3

Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.23.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import torch
   ...: import math
   ...: def add(dtype):
   ...:     device = torch.device("cuda:0")
   ...:     x = torch.ones(5, device=device, dtype=dtype)
   ...:     y = torch.ones(5, device=device, dtype=dtype)
   ...:     r = x + y
   ...:    # print(r)
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     print(torch.abs(r))
   ...: add(torch.float)
   ...: add(torch.bfloat16)
   ...: add(torch.half)
   ...: #add(torch.int)

In [2]:


[I 2024-04-18 13:40:44.904 ServerApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 2024-04-18 13:40:45.009 ServerApp] Writing notebook-signing key to /root/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret
[I 2024-04-18 13:40:45.743 ServerApp] Kernel started: 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02
[I 2024-04-18 13:40:46.316 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02.
[I 2024-04-18 13:40:46.473 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02.
[I 2024-04-18 13:40:46.628 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02.
[I 2024-04-18 13:41:00.723 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
[W 2024-04-18 13:41:00.724 ServerApp] kernel 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02 restarted
[I 2024-04-18 13:41:00.804 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02:0c6f983f-ac45-4390-843a-39ec1a0643e4
[I 2024-04-18 13:41:00.887 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02.
[I 2024-04-18 13:41:00.887 ServerApp] Restoring connection for 0fe4a353-c797-4054-8c43-6854c9590f02:0c6f983f-ac45-4390-843a-39ec1a0643e4

It seems like it can run a bit (I see some cuda logs saying it's processing), but then it restarts the kernel.
However! If I run it in a new kernel, it works fine:
root@3e04896b2103:/# jupyter console --kernel python3
Jupyter console 6.6.3

Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.23.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import torch
   ...: import math
   ...: def add(dtype):
   ...:     device = torch.device("cuda:0")
   ...:     x = torch.ones(5, device=device, dtype=dtype)
   ...:     y = torch.ones(5, device=device, dtype=dtype)
   ...:     r = x + y
   ...:    # print(r)
   ...:     print(x)
   ...:     print(torch.abs(r))
   ...: add(torch.float)
   ...: add(torch.bfloat16)
   ...: add(torch.half)
   ...: #add(torch.int)
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], device='cuda:0')
tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], device='cuda:0')
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16)
tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16)
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
tensor([2., 2., 2., 2., 2.], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)

I even tried as simple as
import torch
import math
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
x = torch.ones(5, device=device, dtype=torch.float)
print(x)

Does anyone know why jupyter's default kernel is not able to handle this? I've been digging through logs and docs all day and can't find any indication of where I can even control the defaults for the kernel that comes with jupyter.
